# How to best implement Save | Save and Close | Cancel form actions in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm wondering how you might go about implementing multiple form actions when submitting a form in asp.net mvc 3 RC.

If I'm editing a user, for example I would like to have an action bar with the following buttons;

**"Save" | "Save and Close" | "Cancel"**

Save - Submits the form and saves, returning you to the edit screen. Could be easily implemented as a standard input/submit button. Nothing special here.

Controller code for this might look like

```
public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel model)
{
  ...
  return RedirectToAction("Edit", model.Id");
}
```

Cancel - Just returns you to previous screen. I was thinking about using an anchor tag for this.

```
<a href="@Request.UrlReferrer" class="button">Cancel</a>
```

But I'm stumped on how to implement **"Save and Close"** when you need to submit the same form data. I was wondering about having a nullable close param maybe?

```
public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel model, bool? close)
{
  ...
  return  close.GetValueOrDefault(false) ? RedirectToAction("Index", model.Id" : RedirectToAction("Edit", model.Id");
}
```

But how do I submit this extra param along with the form in this case?

If possible, I'd like to have a single form action for handling the submit as in the above mockup.

I'm also interested if anyone else has come up with a nice user interaction model around this idea.

**Solution**

I ended up using Omar's suggestion below but instead of passing in a string I took in an enum so I don't have to do string checks in all my controllers.

```
public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel model, FormAction actionType)
{
  // pre-check
  if (actionType == FormAction.Cancel)
     // just return user to previous view and don't save.

  // Save code

  if (actionType == FormAction.Save)
     return ...
  else if (actionType == FormAction.SaveAndClose)
     ....
}
```

Because I wanted a friendlier "Save and Close" text on the `<input>` button but wanted to use an enum I implemented a custom ModelBinder for FormAction that did the parsing.

I didn't use a `<button>` tag because the theming was already in place for `<input>` tags.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can have multiple submit buttons in a form with the same `name` attribute but different `value` attributes. Which ever button is clicked, the associated `value` will be posted to the server.

You can use a simple link for `Cancel` but I'll include it as a button anyway.

```
<input type="submit" name="actionType" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="actionType" value="Save and Close" />
<input type="submit" name="actionType" value="Cancel" />
```

And in your action, test for the values.

```
public ActionResult Edit(string actionType)
{
    if(actionType == "Save")
    {
        // Save action
    }
    else if (actionType == "Save and Close")
    {
        // Save and quit action
    }
    else
    {
        // Cancel action
    }
}
```

If you don't like having the long text in the `value` attribute, you can use standard HTML `<button>` tag which lets you define a separate value and separate text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423041/using-two-submit-buttons-inside-single-form/2426152#2426152

Comment: Thanks Omar. That was exactly what I wanted. Cheers!

Comment: Updated my question with final solution based on this approach. Quite similar, just cleaned up to use an enum instead of strings.

Answer (score 5):

The suggestion by @Omar is great. Here is how I made this a little more generic in the case where I wanted a confirmation when the user is prompted to delete an object. 
Note! in the HttpPost I'm pulling the object again rather than using the item passed to the method. You can reduce a DB call by the having the view contain all the properties so "Item" is populated.

Here's the View Model

```
public class DeleteViewModel<T> {
    public string ActionType { get; set; }
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int id) {
        DeleteViewModel<Category> model = new DeleteViewModel<Category>() {
            Item = categoryRepository.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryID == id)
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(DeleteViewModel<Category> model) {
        if (model.ActionType == "Cancel")
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        else if (model.ActionType == "Delete") {
            var cat = categoryRepository.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryID == model.Item.CategoryID);
            categoryRepository.Delete(cat);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }        
        //Unknown Action
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**View**

```
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="actions-left"><input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="ActionType"/></div>
        <div class="actions-right"><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="ActionType" /></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I like this solution better since it allows you to pass the Model that's being acted on.