# Two different actions on same view in mvc3 with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created one application with mvc3 (Razor) named studentApp. i have one page that is index page. I want to add two actions on the same page.

Action 1: Insert new student.
Action 2: Search the student.

So how should i maintain the two different actions on same view.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have all actions on the view. You have an action that guides your users to the index view, on that view, you have buttons or forms that calls different actions (insertion, search).

Your controllers should be able to recognize which action is being called, process it and call the appropiate view. Also, each view should be able to render the appropiate info depending on the situation.

Comment: I have found some solution on the net with below link.   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339460/can-we-have-mutiple-submits-button-in-a-view-for-different-operations)