# Accessing HTML form elements with same name from javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following solution ([How to best implement Save | Save and Close | Cancel form actions in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263995/how-to-best-implement-save-save-and-close-cancel-form-actions-in-asp-net-mvc)) of multiple submit buttons to allow cancel and save from my MVC form:

```
<form action="Xxxx" method="post" onsubmit="return validatePost()">
...
<input type="submit" name="actionType" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="actionType" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

With javascript called onsubmit:

```
function validatePost() {
    if(Blah blah){
        return true;
    }
}
```

I only want to do this javascript validation if 'Save' is clicked, but cannot tell which button was clicked from the javascript.

I tried getting the actionType value using `document.forms[0].elements["actionType"].value` but could not, as there is more than one item named actionType on the form.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `id` (http://jsfiddle.net/7p5N5/)

```
<form method="post">
<input id="save" type="submit" name="actionType" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="actionType" value="Cancel" />
</form>

function validate() {
    alert('Validate');
    return false; // cancel click, true will submit
}

$("#save").click(function () {
    return validate();
});
```

If you don't want to use `id`, you can use `$('input[name="actionType"][value="Save"]')` to select the Save button

Comment: Ah, seems so simple once you see it - I used the id. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to listen to the onclick event of only the 'Save' input and have it use your validatePost function.

Then you could have a different function for the onclick of 'Cancel' to do appropriate action.