# MVC4 - One form 2 submit buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, submit

I followed the instructions on this post:
[Asp.net mvc3 razor with multiple submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702549/asp-net-mvc3-razor-with-multiple-submit-buttons)
and here is my model:

```
public class AdminModel
{
  public string Command { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Admin(List<AdminModel> model)
{
   string s = model.Command;
}
```

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Admin", "Account"))
{
  <input type="submit" name="Command" value="Deactivate"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Command" value="Delete"/>
}
```

When I post back, string "s" is always null.

I also tried the second answer (the one with 146 votes) in this forum post : [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework) and thats also null.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423041/using-two-submit-buttons-inside-single-form/2426152#2426152

How about this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you need to take the value from their server side by the name of the button,

```
public ActionResult Admin(List<AdminModel> model,string Command)
{
   string s = Command;
}
```

Comment: whoa I thought I tried this, per the second forum on my post. I dont know what I did wrong that time. it works now thanks.

Comment: Note that when using `<button>` tags and not `<input>` tags, pressing Enter in one of the form fields, the `Command` argument will not get set and will therefore be `null`. You can handle that by using Javascript to capture key press events, or by simply by setting a default value in the controller action: `public ActionResult Admin(List<AdminModel> model, string Command = "Deactivate")`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the posted code, you aren't sending a list of models to your controller, just a single model instance. Try modifying the controller to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Admin(AdminModel model)
{
   string s = model.Command;
}
```

Comment: My view was taking in a list of AdminModel :).