# just the first button out of 3 buttons is working - submission with onclick - any ideas what´s wrong?

Tags: php, onclick, buttonclick, survey, submit-button

I had a quiz which I transformed into a page with a submit button. When the button gets clicked also a tracking code is passed to the next page. Then I duplicated the buttons but always just the first button is working. So if I take out the first one, then the second one works but not the others.

I´ve tried to give the buttons different names ...

The expected result is that every button is clickable and the link works. Right now just the first button in the row works.

Comment: May we see these buttons? Please include a [mcve] so we can see what you are working with. It is hard to diagnose a code problem with no code

Comment: make sure the btns don't have the same id

Comment: Does each button have a unique name? Is the `type="submit"` or `type="button"`? If you can't show us what you're working with maybe one of these very similar questions might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120678/multiple-buttons-on-a-form, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423041/using-two-submit-buttons-inside-single-form, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963245/multiple-submit-buttons-on-html-form-designate-one-button-as-default